# Redux reducer is getting over written by setState or .map() in my React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

When I console.log the `this.state.orginalSeries`, `this.props.demandGraphSeriesDataReducer` and `newSeries` I get all of the same mutated data back.

I tried using .map() and .slice() to not mutate the original reducer data but some how it still is getting mutated. I can also see using Redux Devtools it is mutating the state of the reducer as well.

```
class DemandSubDemand extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      orginalSeries: null
    };
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    const copy = this.props.demandGraphSeriesDataReducer.slice()
    this.setState({
      orginalSeries: copy
    })
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.demandGraphSeriesDataReducer!== prevProps.demandGraphSeriesDataReducer) {
      const copy = this.props.demandGraphSeriesDataReducer.slice()
      this.setState({
        orginalSeries: copy
      })
    }
  }

  onValueUpdate(i, value) {
    const newSeries = this.state.orginalSeries.map((line, j) => {
      if(i === j) line.data[i] = line.data[i] + value;
      return line;
    });
  }

render(){
  return <button onClick={()=>this.onValueUpdate(0,100)}> here</button>
}
```

Comment: I don't see a reducer anywhere, nor how you you use `connect` for your component, or where it even might be called. You just seem to handle local state, and your props could come from a reducer or it's parent component, from the code you have shared. When you use `map` however, your `line` would indeed refer to the original entry in your array, you could use a `slice`before the map there (but for some reason, there is no `this.setState` anywhere in the `onValueUpdate` method, so it shouldn't re-render your component

Comment: The parent component is connected to the store which passes down the demandGraphSeriesDataReducer which is a reducer.

Comment: That could be a part you could [edit] in :) But my comment about the `line` referring to the original entry of your array still applies, there you are indeed mutating the `originalSeries` and the original array item in  your reducer. `slice` doesn't do a deepcopy, if you want a deepcopy and you have no circular references, you should do better using `JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( this.props.demandGraphSeriesDataReducer ) )`. Calling an array a reducer however could be problematic naming...

Comment: Ahh that did it. Its not pretty but works. Thanks mate!

Comment: That's great, I personally don't mind the solution when you need to do a full copy of an object :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( this.props.demandGraphSeriesDataReducer ) )` in place of `slice` worked per @icepickle 's advice

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the mutation may be here:

```js
  onValueUpdate(i, value) {
    const newSeries = this.state.orginalSeries.map((line, j) => {
      if(i === j) line.data[i] = line.data[i] + value;
      return line;
    });
  }
```

In particular, `line.data[i] =` is going to mutate the existing `line` object in the original array.  You would need to [make copies of every level of nesting in the data](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-nested-objects) for it to not mutate.

I'd strongly encourage you to use the [`configureStore()` function from Redux Starter Kit](https://redux-starter-kit.js.org/api/configureStore), which adds a mutation checker by default.  Also, consider using [Immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) for simpler immutable updates.  Redux Starter Kit's [`createReducer()` and `createSlice()` functions](https://redux-starter-kit.js.org/api/createSlice) use Immer internally by default.